# continuous implies frechet differentiable?

Tags: continuity

I knew if $f$ is Frechet differentiable at $x$ then $f$ is continuous at $x$. But reverse, i.e. If $f$ is continuous at $x$ then $f$ is Frechet differentiable at $x$ true or false?. I think it is wrong, but I can't give a counterexample. Can anyone give me a counterexample?. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The space $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual absolute value is a normed vector space, and the Frechet derivative coincides with the ordinary derivative.[1]  Now can you come up with continuous functions that are not (Frechet-)differentiable?

[1] If $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, then its Frechet derivative at $x$ is the bounded linear operator defined as multiplication by $f'(x)$.

Comment: let $f(x)=|x|$ then $f$ is continuous at $0$, but not differentiable. Ok

Comment: @Muniain There you go, you've answered your question :)